# Wrong order of sorting in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

Data structure looks like:

```
ID       | Name      |  CID
---------------------------------
1        | x         |  
2        | a         |  12
3        | a         |  12   
4        | c         |  
5        | x         |  
6        | [         |
```

When I perform the ordinary queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table WHERE ISNull(CID_ID) ORDER BY Name;  [1]

SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table ORDER BY Name; [2]
```

I get the expected result for [1] in the MySQL CLI:

```
| Name      
------------
| c         
| x         
| [
```

And for query [2]:

```
| Name      
------------
| a        
| c         
| x         
| [
```

---

**So my problem is:** When I open the recordset and bind it to a field list, the order of the items is messed up. In detail, the dataset with bracket value "[" is placed on the top of the field list in the MS-Access form, but only when i perform query [1].

I get the **NOT** the expected result for [1]:

```
| Name      
------------
| [   
| c         
| x
```

And for query [2]:

```
| Name      
------------
| a        
| c         
| x         
| [
```

The simplified VBA code snippet looks like this:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table WHERE ISNull(CID_ID) ORDER BY Name;"
Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

After i catched the recordset, i override the recordset of the list:

```
Set Me.ListNames.Recordset = oiManager.LoadDistinctName()
```

---

**Additional information (1):**

*Server version: 5.6.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)*

---

**Additional information (2):**

```
| Name       | Engine | Version | Collation
| ########## | InnoDB |      10 | utf8_general_ci
```

---

**Additional information (3):**
So I created two separate queries in access and fired them up. In the datasheet view i get the "swapped result": for query [1] it's on the top, for query [2] the bracket is on the bottom. It's an linked MySQL table with ODBC connection. I played around with some of the table properties but with no effect.

Then I created a dummy table in access itself, filled the table with some values and the result was consistent: both times displayed on the top. So in my opinion, the inconsistency must base upon the fact that I'm using a linked MySQL table.

I'm using:

- Microsoft Access 2013 (9.0.24172.951362)
- ODBC-Driver 32-Bit, MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver

Comment: What database are you using, mysql or access?

Comment: Update: see the bottom of the post.

Comment: Your sample output shows that the two Access queries are inconsistent in their sorting of the `[` to the top/bottom. Is that actually the case? (I'm not seeing that in my tests.) Also, what is the collation setting on the MySQL table?

Comment: Yes, it's the inconsistent of the sorting order, which i'm not able to fix. For additional information, please take a look at the updated version. Thanky you!

Comment: I'm not talking about the difference between MySQL and Access, I'm talking about when Access runs the two queries. Does Access really put the `[` first when it runs query [1] and put the `[` last when it runs query [2]?

Comment: Yes - i've searched for an answer about an hour or so. I will check it again tomorrow, when i'am back on my desk. Even if i copied the query directly into the source field of the field list, the bracket was showed on top of the field list. Could it also be an issue with the underlying ODBC-Connection? Or some other misconfiguration?

Comment: And yes - the values swapped just by changing the two statements.

Comment: Okay, please check that because when I run the two queries from within Access the `[` appears at the top consistently (i.e., for *both* query [1] and query [2]). If that is the case for you too then please edit the sample results in your question to reflect that. (A difference in behaviour between MySQL and Access is one thing, but *inconsistent* behaviour from Access is something different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your results. The change in sorting behaviour appears to be related to using the `IsNull()` function. When I change query [1] to

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [table] WHERE [CID_ID] IS NULL ORDER BY [Name];
```

then the ordering is consistent for both query [1] and query [2] (and is the same as the MySQL queries).

My guess is that the revised query is "plain" SQL and gets handed to the ODBC driver directly, while the original `IsNull()` query required that the ACE/Jet Expression Service become involved, and consequently the final sorting was the way Access normally does it for queries against native ACE/Jet tables.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort!